# A streamer's diet

Tags: logical-deduction, story, logic-grid

I'm in dire need of help.

I've been hired to take care of a certain streamer during a charity event, but the instructions they gave me for meals and games are just, way too confusing!
This one streamer has 5 meals, 5 games, and all that during 5 days, but on Friday apparently he doesn't play games! This is where you come in, I need your help figuring this out...
So, the instructions are:

- No games on Friday, the streamer just chats and answers questions
- For roguelikes, pork or chicken is preferred
- Wednesday's meal needs to be vegan, "Wegan Wednesday" is a thing apparently
- Tuesday is a big day, a big meal is needed
- Monday is rice day, only meals that contain rice are accepted
- DOOD is played on either Wednesday or Thursday
- Shades is addictive, once you start you can't stop
- Elder King needs a quick meal, so either the salad or sandwich
- The pasta will be eaten on Friday or Tuesday
- Either the pasta or salad will be eaten during DOOD
- The chili was eaten while switching from a game to a sandbox
- All games will be played once

Ah, and here's some information about the games and meals.

Meals:

- Chili con Carne (Beef with red beans, rice, and tomato, very caloric meal)
- Tofu Salad (Tofu squares with lettuce and corn, light meal)
- Chicken Curry (Chicken cooked with curry spices, served with rice, very caloric meal)
- Pasta with Salmon (Salmon lightly cooked and added to pasta, regular meal)
- Club Sandwich (Pork ham, lettuce, tomato, cheese between white bread, light meal)

Games:

- Elder King (Action-Adventure, long game about a king exploring his domain)
- Shades (Roguelike, a game about a shade escaping hell)
- Banjo-Kazoo (Platformer, a colorful adventure of a bear and his kazoo)
- Mineraft (Sandbox, an infinite game about building a raft)
- DOOD (Action, a shooter about a dude wishing for revenge against demons)

That should be all the info you need, now please, help me know that streamer's schedule and meals!

Comment: I've been trying my hand at more diverse style of puzzles, feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Loving the names! Do I understand correctly that this is more than a straightforward logic grid deduction puzzle since after putting in all the clues, I still have fields that can go either way due to circular logic? Also, the point is that one of the days, two games are played, or is there some kind of trick in wording I am supposed to spot?

Comment: That's becoming a habit of mine to need to edit puzzles it seems, will fix right now!

Comment: Shades (read sha-DEES) pog.

Comment: I still seem to be stuck, but I managed to progress enough to post  a partial solution, maybe it will help others to get started.

Comment: Just curious, what's Shades a parody of? Also Banjo-Kazoo

Comment: @justhalf Shades is a parody of "Hades", a popular roguelike, Banjo-Kazoo is the old platformer "Banjo-Kazooie", I assume you've caught Minecraft (Mineraft), DOOM (DOOD) and Elden Ring (Elder King)

Comment: Thanks! I've never played Hades and Banjo-Kazooie, so I don't know them. And you assumed correctly about the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solved puzzle, below it all the logic in order:

> Monday - chicken curry, Shades

> Tuesday - chili con carne, Banjo-Kazoo then Mineraft

> Wednesday - tofu salad, DOOD

> Thursday - club sandwich, Elder King

> Friday - salmon pasta, no game

Here's the logic step by step, more or less.

> Wednesday is the easiest. It has to be the salad (the only vegan meal) for food.
>  We can also conclude that DOOD is the game to be played, because

> it is combined with either pasta or salad, but days for pasta (Tuesday and Friday) do not overlap with days for DOOD (Wednesday and Thursday). This leaves salad as the only option.

> So, on Wednesday, salad is eaten and DOOD is played.

Next thing to observe is Monday and Tuesday

> map to the same two meals - the curry and the chili. Both contain rice and both are considered "big meals". No other meals satisfy either requirements, which means these two are fixed to these two days, in yet unknown order.

This leaves Thursday and Friday meals to be figured out, luckily we can lock it down fairly easily:

> the pasta has to be on Friday, because it cannot be on Tuesday due to previous hints.
>  this means the sandwich is for Thursday, the only remaining option.

Having fixed these days, we can place

> Elder king on Thursday as it cannot be played with the salad which is enjoyed together with DOOD already.

Friday has no games, so the remaining 3 games have to be distributed between two days somehow, meaning either there's a day with 2 games as well, or a day with 3 games and one more day with no games.

This is the current state of the puzzle then:

> Monday - either chili or curry, any remaining games

> Tuesday - same as Monday

> Wednesday - tofu salad, DOOD

> Thursday - club sandwich, Elder King

> Friday - salmon pasta, no game

I am stuck here and unable to distinguish between Monday and Tuesday, as the only information I have about the meals gives two possibilities, and no information regarding the games, except for one constraint:

> Whichever day will have the curry will also have at least the Shades game played as it is preferred to go with either pork or chicken, and pork is not possible as it is eaten on Thursday with Elder King.

I also have a small hunch that

> Tuesday might be the day with two games, as it is the "big" day, but it does not seem like a proper clue.

With the finalisation of the puzzle and author's comment, we have the following logic bits:

> Shades is played as the only game on its day, and chicken curry will be eaten during. This is further supported by the other meal being stated to be eaten between two games.

> That leaves the other day with two games, Banjo-Kazoo and Mineraft, and chili as the meal of the day (Banjo is played first).

Based on the response of the author ("your hunch was correct"), we will take the clue as a proper one and conclude that

> Monday, Shades is played and chicken curry is eaten, and

> Tuesday, Banjo-Kazoo is played, then Mineraft (the chili is eaten between the two)

Comment: I have got to exactly the same position. So either this isn't a pure logic puzzle (despite the tags), or it's missing some essential information.

Comment: that's what I am wondering as well

Comment: Deepest apologies, your hunch is indeed correct but I was missing a thing when editing, I will finalize it right now!

Comment: @Auribouros I have edited the rest of the solution based on your adjustments now. It was fun to solve and the games were hilarious :-)